# Why is only the last step in my javascript not working?

Tags: javascript, loops

Why is only the last step in my script not working? The rest is working ok.
Error: file number 30 should have name C, but it gets name A from this statement below.
Why is this loop not renaming file 30 with C? (as is the rest renamed C correct)

Details:
I am using a script to rename files. I have 3 names in a sequence A, B and C.

The first 10 files are renamed with A
The next 10 with B
The next 10 with C
Then the next 10 again with A
Then the next 10 with B
etc.

Script/ statement

---

```
var X = 3; //different statements
var Y = 10; //files per statement

if  (counter) {

    index = (counter)%(X*Y);
    if (index <= Y)         newName += '_A_';
    else if (index <= Y*2)     newName += '_B_';
    else if (index <= Y*3)     newName += '_C_';

}
```

I have isolated this problem to be only in the last number of the last sequence step (C in this example). The rest is working ok.

Comment: You should really use brackets for all statements that support them; also, name your variables after what they represent, so instead of `X`, it could be `sequenceSteps`. Then you wouldn't need a comment to remind you. You should consider learning how to use a debugger to step through the code line by line; that will tell you exactly what's going wrong, when, and why.

Comment: I agree, comments to describe are often a "code smell' of poor name choices.

Comment: Why tag "loops" there are no loops here. `index =` and `counter` are undefined here.

Comment: I have rolled back your edit which removed the question from your question, it may be useful to someone else with the same or a a similar issue - please don't do this! You have accepted an answer and that is enough to mark the question as resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
var X = 3; // sequence steps
var Y = 10; // files per sequence step

if (counter) {
    index = (counter - 1) % (X * Y);

    if (index < Y) {
        newName += '_A_';
    } else if (index < Y * 2) {
        newName += '_B_';
    } else if (index <= Y * 3) {
        newName += '_C_';
    }
}
```

Comment: Good answers come with an explanation of what changed and why...

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Please explain what you have changed and why! It is not obvious from the answer as it is currently written what the issue was!